# Can this query be made without a subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, left-join, sql-in

Imagine these 3 tables:

```
User             Login:            LoginInfo:
----             -----             -----
id:integer       id:integer        id:integer
name:string      user_id:integer   login_id:integer
```

Is is possible to select all the Users that don't have `LoginInfos` without doing a subquery/subselect ( I wrote this without checking it against the DB ):

```
select id from users 
where id not in (
  select distinct(user_id) from logins 
  right join login_infos on logins.id = login_infos.login_id
)
```

I'm using Postgres as database.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a subquery? What you've written can be optimized if you're having performance problems.

Comment: I remember reading it's not very optimal to use subqueries.

Comment: `select all the Users that don't have LoginInfos`. So clarify: do they need to have an entry in `Login`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why the **`RIGHT JOIN`**?

You potentially add `NULL` to the result of the subquery, which is a common pitfall in a `NOT IN` construct.

Consider this simple demo:

```
SELECT 5 NOT IN (VALUES (1), (2), (3))         --> TRUE
      ,5 NOT IN (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (NULL)) --> NULL (!)
      ,5     IN (VALUES (1), (2), (3))         --> FALSE
      ,5     IN (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (NULL)) --> NULL (!)
```

In other words:
*"We do not know whether `5` is in the set, since at least one element is unknown and could be 5."*
Since in a `WHERE` clause only `TRUE` is relevant (neither `NULL` nor `FALSE` pass the test), it wouldn't affect `WHERE id IN (...)` at all.

But it affects

```
WHERE id NOT IN (...)
```

This expression **never** qualifies as soon as there is a `NULL` in the right hand set.
Probably not as intended?

---

### Solution

The requirement is to

> select all the Users that don't have LoginInfos

This can include users that don't have a row in table `login` either. Therefore, we need `LEFT JOIN` two times. And since it is not defined whether one user can have multiple rows in `login`, we also need `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.*
FROM   users u
LEFT   JOIN login     l ON l.user_id  = u.id
LEFT   JOIN logininfo i ON i.login_id = l.id
WHERE  i.login_id IS NULL
```

This covers all eventualities. You *can* ...

- remove the `DISTINCT` if there can be *at most* one login per user.
- replace the first `LEFT JOIN` with `JOIN` if there is *at least* one row in `login` for every user.

This *alternative* with [`NOT EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) uses a subquery.
But it works no matter how many rows per user there can be in table `login`. And it doesn't exhibit any of the aforementioned problems of `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM   users u
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   login     l
   JOIN   logininfo i ON i.login_id = l.id
   WHERE  l.user_id = u.id
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct u.id
from
    user u
    inner join
    login l on u.id = l.user_id
    left join
    logininfo li on l.id = li.login_d
where li.id is null
```